# tell wpf how to render on tab change

Tags: wpf, user-controls, tabcontrol, itemscontrol, itemssource

I have an itemscontrol in a tabcontrol.
I bind my viewmodel to the itemssource of it and use a usercontrol as the itemstemplate.

When I run the programm wpf renders the itemscontrol not until I click on the tab it's in.

As I have a lot of items to render my program freezes for 10 secs.

**Question:**

Where can I tell my application for example to render one item in my itemssource, update my view and then render one item again and so on?

Comment: Add the items to an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ItemsControl` one ny one with some delay in between? And make sure that you haven't disabled the UI virtualization.

Comment: I want the UI virtualization disabled. Is it enabled it takes maybe half a second but for another reason I cannot do that. And I bind my ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection. The problem is WPF is rendering it only after I click on the Tab my ItemsControl is in.

Comment: An itemscontrol doesn't have a virtualising stackpanel (or sliders). It just has a stackpanel and will render ALL it's contents. A Listbox or listview has a virtualising stackpanel to host items and will not render contents which are not going to be visible. The itemscontrol was a bad choice. Make it a listbox instead.  10 seconds seems a LOT by the way.

Comment: @Andy as I said I do not want virtualization. And you could use a virtualising stackpanel in the itemspaneltemplate. I want to load all items. But what I don't want is that all items are rendered and then the UI gets updated but to load one by one item and update the UI after each item. Is there a way to change this rendering mode? And yeah I have a lot of usercontrols which need to be displayed...

Comment: You could write your own panel and handle how it renders each item. Or you could add each item separately to a bound observablecollection await task.delay then add next... etc.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your answer. Do you have any link or anything where it is described how I have to override the onrender method of an itemscontrol?